# Как объединить два массива вершин и индексов?

Tags: opengl

Хочу объединить vertires и vertires1 в один. тоже самое для indices и indices1.
 Один отрисовывает горизонтальные линии(vertires, indices) на сцене, а другой вертикальные (vertires1, indices1).

```
    // 1. Настройка массива вершин для линий
    GLfloat vertires[] = {
        // горизонтальные линнии (отрицательная сторона)
        -0.9f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //0
        -0.8f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //1
        -0.7f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //2
        -0.6f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //3
        -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //4
        -0.4f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //5
        -0.3f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //6
        -0.2f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //7
        -0.1f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //8
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //9

        -0.9f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //10
        -0.8f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //11
        -0.7f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //12
        -0.6f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //13
        -0.5f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //14
        -0.4f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //15
        -0.3f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //16
        -0.2f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //17
        -0.1f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //18
         0.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //19

        //--- (положительная сторона)
        0.9f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //20
        0.8f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //21
        0.7f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //22
        0.6f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //23
        0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //24
        0.4f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //25
        0.3f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //26
        0.2f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //27
        0.1f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //28

        0.9f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //29
        0.8f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //30
        0.7f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //31
        0.6f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //32
        0.5f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //33
        0.4f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //34
        0.3f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //35
        0.2f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //36
        0.1f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, //37

    };

    GLfloat vertires1[] = {
        // вериткальные линнии (отрицательная сторона)
        1.0f,  -0.9f, 0.0f, //0
        1.0f,  -0.8f, 0.0f, //1
        1.0f,  -0.7f, 0.0f, //2
        1.0f,  -0.6f, 0.0f, //3
        1.0f,  -0.5f, 0.0f, //4
        1.0f,  -0.4f, 0.0f, //5
        1.0f,  -0.3f, 0.0f, //6
        1.0f,  -0.2f, 0.0f, //7
        1.0f,  -0.1f, 0.0f, //8
        1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, //9

        -1.0f, -0.9f, 0.0f, //10
        -1.0f, -0.8f, 0.0f, //11
        -1.0f, -0.7f, 0.0f, //12
        -1.0f, -0.6f, 0.0f, //13
        -1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //14
        -1.0f, -0.4f, 0.0f, //15
        -1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f, //16
        -1.0f, -0.2f, 0.0f, //17
        -1.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f, //18
        -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //19

        //--- (положительная сторона)
        1.0f, 0.9f, 0.0f, //20
        1.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f, //21
        1.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f, //22
        1.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, //23
        1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, //24
        1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f, //25
        1.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f, //26
        1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, //27
        1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, //28

        -1.0f, 0.9f, 0.0f, //29
        -1.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f, //30
        -1.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f, //31
        -1.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, //32
        -1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, //33
        -1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f, //34
        -1.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f, //35
        -1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, //36
        -1.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, //37
    };

    GLuint indices[] = {
        0, 10,
        1, 11,
        2, 12,
        3, 13,
        4, 14,
        5, 15,
        6, 16,
        7, 17,
        8, 18,
        9, 19,
        //--
        20, 29,
        21, 30,
        22, 31,
        23, 32,
        24, 33,
        25, 34,
        26, 35,
        27, 36,
        28, 37,

    };
    GLuint indices1[] = {
        0, 10,
        1, 11,
        2, 12,
        3, 13,
        4, 14,
        5, 15,
        6, 16,
        7, 17,
        8, 18,
        9, 19,
        //--
        20, 29,
        21, 30,
        22, 31,
        23, 32,
        24, 33,
        25, 34,
        26, 35,
        27, 36,
        28, 37,
    };
```

пытался вот так `indices = indices + indices1; vertires = vertires+ vertires1;` но так сразу ошибка.

Попробовал так, но воз снова не там:

```
GLuint vbo, ibo,  vao;

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);                   
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);      
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertires), vertires, GL_STATIC_DRAW);   
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertires1), vertires1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);     // почему то использует последний буфер а перед ним нет

glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices1), indices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // почему то использует последний буфер а перед ним нет
```

Как объединить буферы и чтоб они не сбились и нормально все отрисовали ?

---

Более обобщённо, у меня есть "сцена" по сути разлинованный экран,
 и я пытаюсь добавить ещё элементы (синус вывести на сцене ) . НО я не хочу их пихать в один и тот же массив вершин и индексов. Ибо думаю что работать с отдельным массивом  вершин и индексов будет проще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прежде чем нажимать минус , удосужитесь аргументировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, вам надо создать новый массив вершин, размером с оба массива имеющихся вершин и туда скопировать первый и второй массивы. А вот с индексами чуть сложнее, так же надо создать массив и скопировать, но все индексы второго массива индексов увеличить на размер первого массива вершин (чтобы они использовали соответствующие вершины из нового массива).

Comment: как же тогда рисовать новые элементы ????

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Правильно вы все думаете. так а что вам мешает выводить разные объекты, не объединяя все в один?