# Не получаеться изменить цвет примитива

Tags: opengl

**Хочу поменять цвет синусойды.** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого сделал загрузку шедевров(фрагментный и вершинный) в функции где отрисовываю синусойду , и меняю в фрагметном шейдере цвет.

```
ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
shaderProgram.loadShaders("basic.vert", "basic.frag");
shaderProgram.use();
shaderProgram.setUniform("vertColor", glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)); // изменил цвет
```

**basic.vert**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
};
```

**basic.frag**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 frag_color;
void main()
{
   frag_color = vec4(0.35f, 0.96f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
};
```

Но почему то  не отрабатывает.

Comment: Так ведь у вас в шейдере нет `uniform`'а `vertColor`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat      сделал так  `shaderProgram.setUniform("frag_color", glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));` но заработало . Как мне поправить шейдер ?? Просто из примеров у меня есть только  такой вариант : `#version 330 core`                                                                                          `uniform vec4 vertColor; out vec4 frag_color; void main() {frag_color = vertColor;}` Не понимаю что в шейдере надо написать.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но после этого и [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904895/) вопросов у меня такое ощущение, что вы изучаете GL методом тыка. `setUniform("frag_color"` не будет работать, потому что `frag_color` - не uniform. *"Просто из примеров у меня есть только такой вариант: ..."* По идее, он должен работать. Вы его пробовали?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня есть две книги [Open GL 4. Язык шейдеров. Книга рецептов](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/978-5-97060-255-3/)  и [OpenGL ES 3.0 Руководство разработчика.](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/978-5-97060-256-0/) , в печатном виде. НО они весьма сложны(в восприятии для меня) и в них маловато примеров. Тот вариант из примеров работает но как его перенести в мой я не знаю

Comment: *"как его перенести в мой я не знаю"* В чем конкретно сложность? Заменяете код в basic.frag на тот, который привели в комментарии. Делаете `shaderProgram.setUniform("vertColor", glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Изменил **basic.frag** . *Спасибо  HolyBlackCat -у :3*

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec4 vertColor;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
   if(vertColor == 0)
       frag_color = vec4(0.35f, 0.96f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
   else
       frag_color = vertColor;
};
```

Либо можно сделать вызов

```
  shaderProgram.setUniform("vertColor", glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]